# Get all values from a list of objects using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**I have a list of objects:**

```
[Object { name="abc", id=12, addr="random addr 0"}, Object { name="def", id=76, addr="random addr 1"}]
```

**What I want:**

Key value pairs of `name -> id`

```
Object { abc=12, def=76}
```

**What I have have:**

```
for (var i in list){
    res[list[i].name]=list[i].id;
}
```

**My question:**

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you realize that this `Object { abc=12, def=76}` isn't valid Javascript?  Do you mean `{ abc:12, def:76}`?

Comment: Yes. Well it prints `Object { abc=12, def=76}` in the firebug console.

Comment: So your problem is, that you don't know how to iterate a list.

Comment: No. My question was to get a better solution (that @rplantiko provided).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most index operations on arrays there are better alternatives (e.g. expressions with map(), reduce(), etc.). In this case, I would suggest reduce():

```
var s = [{ name:"abc", id:12, addr:"random addr 0"}, 
         { name:"def", id:76, addr:"random addr 1"}]; 
s.reduce( function( acc, next) { 
   acc[next.name] = next.id; 
   return acc; 
   }, {} )
```

gives

```
Object {abc: 12, def: 76}
```

Comment: Why is reduce any better than other iteration methods here such as `.forEach()`?  When you're not changing the accumulator value, I don't see how reduce offers anything over other means of iteration.

Comment: The accumulator value _is_ changed - with each iteration, the hash grows by one new member - and this is precisely why `reduce` is a good approach for this problem, being of the type "Add something to the `acc` with each list entry, and in the end return `acc` as result"

Comment: You're adding a property to the variable the accumulator points to, but not changing the accumulator variable itself.  I still don't see how `.reduce()` offers anything useful here over other forms of iterating.  I find Artjom's answer much easier code to follow.

Comment: `acc` does not "point to a variable" but _is_ a variable, pointing to some memory segment (technically); the content of this segment is what we call its value, and this value is changed with each iteration (as I wrote). This is a typical `reduce` task. Of course, every `reduce` can be written as a `forEach` instead, with the accumulator variable declared separately, like in Artjom's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all list items and add a property to the intended object.

```
var res = {};
list.forEach(function(item){
    return res[item.name] = item.id;
});
```

or for general array like objects

```
var res = {};
Arrays.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(item){
    return res[item.name] = item.id;
});
```

or in old school iteration

```
var res = {};
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    return res[list[i].name] = list[i].id;
});
```

Comment: If you're going to use `.forEach` on an array, why not just `list.forEach()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Because you can't be sure every time that it is an array. In this case I probably could just do `list.forEach`. This general approach also works for objects that are accessed like arrays.

Comment: The OP uses array syntax.

Comment: I am already iterating through a list. You can see that in the question. `.foreach()` might be slightly better though.

Comment: @user2815547 What better way can there be than iterating through the list. Elements won't magically rearrange themselves. Reduce looks eloquent but does it really provide something better? Is it easier to read? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation, using **[JQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** function ($.map)

```
var list = [{ 'name':"abc", 'id':12, 'addr':"random addr 0"},
            { 'name':"def", 'id':76, 'addr':"random addr 1"}];

var result = {};
$.map(list,function (i){ result[i.name] = i.id})

console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
Object {abc: 12, def: 76}
```

Comment: `$.map` should probably be `$.each` because you don't return anything.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jquery .map

I did as follows

`var PAIDs = SU.Details.Actions.map(function (pa) { return pa.id; });`

which gave me an array of objects with just the id